# R: add column based on existing column relationship

Tags: r, graph

I have a data frame that I'm using to tabularly represent a directed graph relationship. Right now I am considering three nodes at a time. I have the relation between node1 and node2, and the relation between node2 and node3, each of which have corresponding edge weights. In rare cases there is a relationship between node1 and node3, but I am having trouble isolating it.
In essence, I have A -> B, and B -> C, and want to find A -> C.
Here is an example of the data frame.

```
df
      node1    node2   weight1     node2_a     node3   weight2
       5         2        .2          2         7        .3
       10        20       .4         20         30       .6
       10        30       .3         30         8        .3
```

So, I would essentially like to have another three columns, which would read like this

```
new_df
      node1    node2   weight1     node2_a     node3   weight2   node1.a     node3.a     weight3
       5         2        .2          2         7        .3         na          na          na
       10        20       .4         20         30       .6         10          30          .3
       10        30       .3         30         8        .3         na          na         na
```

I understand there may be better ways to do this, but I'm curious how I can make it work like this. Thanks, if this is unclear I am happy to explain further.

Comment: I think data.table might be my best bet, along with maybe a left join, but can't get it quite right.

Comment: What are the relationships between 1 and 2, 2 and 3?

Answer (score 0):

This gives you more or less what you need...

```
merge(df, df[1:3], 
      by.x=c("node1","node3"), by.y=c("node1","node2"), 
      all.x=TRUE)

  node1 node3 node2 weight1.x node2_a weight2 weight1.y
1     5     7     2       0.2       2     0.3        NA
2    10     8    30       0.3      30     0.3        NA
3    10    30    20       0.4      20     0.6       0.3
```

This reorders the dataframe, but that may not matter.  You might like to reorder and rename the columns (`weight1.y` is your `weight3`), and to add your `node1.a` and `node3.a` columns as equal to `node1` and `node3` for those rows for which `weight1.y` is not `NA`.

Comment: This is excellent and exactly what I was trying to do. Thanks very much.